# What is the small blue circle in the Chrome console log?

Tags: google-chrome, console

I'm logging dynamic JavaScript code into my Chrome console using `console.log`.

Sometimes I get a small blue circle on one line with a number in it.

Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The number of times that output has been repeated, also known as log stacking.

Answer (score 15):

This is called "message stacking". From [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#message_stacking):

> #### Message stacking
>
> If a message is consecutively repeated, rather than printing out each instance of the message on a new line, the Console "stacks" the messages and shows a number in the left margin instead. The number indicates how many times the message has repeated.

It can be turned off by enabling "Show timestamps" for the Console in general settings.