# Can we use log stacking in a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

I am working with functionality that shows the number and a log stacking. A log stack basically shows how many times a particular output occurs ([What is the small blue circle in the Chrome console log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088145/what-is-the-small-blue-circle-in-the-chrome-console-log)). But can I use this to setup a condition like,

```
    if (output is between 0 and 25) || (it occurs for like more then 25 times){
          //block of code to be executed if the condition is true    
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Sure you can implement your own stacking functionality, and evaluate any conditions you want on it. But no, there is no way to access the outputs of `console.log` if that is what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really check how many times it occurs. What you can do is to check the number by storing it in a variable or else.